# cv2.waitKey does not detect the input key in flask blueprint. Works normally in app.run()

Tags: python, opencv

I run the same code to save the current frame from my rtsp camera as a local file, upon key press from Flask.

But, `cv2.waitKey()` does not detect the key input, when I execute flask run thru the terminal along the blueprint and its value remains in -1. But, when executed using `app.run()` inside the main function, it works fine. **I badly need to use the blueprint for my app's login.**

`cv2.namedWindow()` is there already.

There are no other differences on other parts of the web app.

```
while stream.isOpened():
   flag, img_rd = stream.read()        # Get camera video stream
   dim = (640, 480)
   img_rd = cv2.resize(img_rd, dim)
   kk = cv2.waitKey(1)
   print(kk)

   if kk & 0xFF == ord('s'):
      print("Save the current frame")
      #Code to save current frame using imwrite
      ...
      ...

   elif kk & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

   else:
      print(kk)
   

   self.update_fps()
   cv2.startWindowThread()
   cv2.namedWindow("Face Registration", 1)
   cv2.imshow("Face Registration", img_rd)
```

~**Edit 1:**

This prints -1 as the value of the variable `kk`, and crashes the everything including flask and exits abruptly without any error message. **I need the app to continue to the main blueprint as this is just one function.**

Pressing any key returns this response, within the window focus.

I can't happen to apply `keyboard.is_pressed('')` as it requires root access.

Does Blueprint have an impact on waitkey()?
What shall be the solution to overcome this issue?

Having tried almost all github & stackoverflow solutions, I'm writing here.

~
**Edit 2:**

I tried directly to knock out the point, `if kk == -1:`. But same thing happens again here. I feel the issue is somewhere else, but couldn't figure out as `app.run()` gets me a proper output. Any help shall be appreciated.

Comment: is the window in focus? Afair waitKey doesnt work if a non-opencv window has user-focus

Comment: @Micka Yeah, on focus. I've edited the main thread with more info. Pl do check.

Comment: are you calling startWindowThread and nanedWindow in every iteration? I think you should do this only once before entering the loop (and maybe from the main thread). And another thing: You dont have any other waitKey calls in your code, right?

Comment: Yeah, they are inside the while loop as I need to show the boundary around my object which gotta get updated in the loop isn't? Yes, only once waitkey is called.

Comment: namedWindow only creates the window. You can call that once before the first imshow. With imshow you can update the window content (rendering a new image to it). Please try: move namedWindow and startWindowThread before the loop. Maybe move imshow to before the waitKey call (not strictly necessary). Can you try (just for testing) to use a waitKey(0) and press any key before fetching the next image).

Comment: @Micka waitKey(0) is not allowing the next frame to be pulled. I tried moving them both outside, yet stuck still in the same issue.

Now, my only doubt is that, all this code is being called in the `main` blueprint as a function call. Imported from `.filename` in my `__init__,py`. And when the user triggers a button, this object detection code will run. Any issue in function import maybe?

Comment: this means the key presses dont arrive at the opencv window. Maybe flask or the blueprint thing is stealing the gui events? Don't have experience with them, sorry.

Comment: Thank you. What you meant seems to be the actual error, 'cause if I try to run the function without flask, it works as expected (inside the flask folder). Therefore, there's some issue with the blueprint.